# Newbie Spring Transaction question from controller

Tags: spring, rest, jpa, transactions

I'm using a spring REST controller & have a situation where both REST  client call the controller to get values to be processed however I'm finding that they are both getting the same values to process when they both call the controller at the same time. I'm using JPA with hibernate as the  provider.

I know that I need to scope the calls into separate transactions (which I have done by putting the @Transactional annotation on the controller method) but finding that they are still getting the same values.

*Device 1 - Timestamp 0: Calls to Controller*

**Controller A:** Reads from event queue all "pending" events

**Controller A:** Update "pending" events to "processed" events

*Device 2 - Timestamp 0: Calls to Controller*

**Controller B:** Reads from event queue all "pending" events

**Controller B:** Update "pending" events to "processed" events

Controller B should not the values that Controller A has picked up & Processed...

So what i expect that i'm looking for is a "read lock" across transactions.

I'm interested in scalability so want to adopt the best approach that help scalability (i.e. only want to hold the DB transaction for as short as possible)...
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Controller B and Controller A, being started "at the same time", see the same events from the queue. Only after one of the controllers commits its transaction the queue is changed.

It is difficult to describe "the best approach" from such a short problem description. There are several possible ways to do it, for example, using the transactional messaging (JMS) or even doing "get the next pending event and mark it as locked" in a new transaction (but then you need a way to unlock it if the processing of the event fails).

Comment: Thanks - I don' want to go down the JMS route as this would be a complete redesign....

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have to employ "some mechanism" that would tell your other controller about what events are already being processed. So that would mean having a mechanism which would lock the events until they are being processed. Somthing like what was suggested earlier "get the next pending event and mark it as locked". unlock it if the transaction committed/rolledback with appropriate status.

Hope that helps.